# How to disable browser launch when building and running in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm developing a Web API with .NET Core in macOS with deployment to Linux. I have absolutely no interest in using the browser. However, **when building and running from Visual Studio Code** (Debug or not), **the browser launches every time**.

I have to close the tab, remove the browser out of the way, go to Paw, where I actually test the API, then go back to VS Code.

It's really annoying doing this every time.

Isn't there some configuration to disable browser launch?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Short Answer

Open the `.vscode/launch.json` file and disable `launchBrowser`.

## More Details

1. `dotnet new webapi`
2. Open VS Code.
3. Add required assets to build and debug.

At this point, there is a `.vscode` directory that contains a `launch.json` file. Open that file and disable or delete the following.

```
"launchBrowser": {
    "enabled": true,
    "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
    "windows": {
        "command": "cmd.exe",
        "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
    },
    "osx": {
        "command": "open"
    },
    "linux": {
       "command": "xdg-open"
    }
},
```

See also: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations

Comment: Yeah it only got annoying after the 1000th development cycle.

Answer (score 74):

It is changed in version 0.2.0.

Just comment out the below lines.

```
// "serverReadyAction": {
//     "action": "openExternally",
//     "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
// },
```

Comment: Same here - `launchBrowser` has no effect even when setting `"enabled": false`.

Comment: the documentation for this is here: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser

Answer (score 10):

## Short Answer

Open the `Properties/launchSettings.json` file and set `"launchBrowser": false`. It works for Visual Studio 2019.

## More Details

1. Go to the project location
2. Open the `Properties/launchSettings.json`
3. Set `"launchBrowser": false`

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MyApi": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Just to add, it works for Visual Studio 2017 as well (Not only VS Code). The file is called **launchSettings.json**, and is located inside the *Properties* folder of the project.

Comment: With the `launch.json` in `.vscode` folder, this solution won't work.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, the auto-generated `launch.json` contained this section:

```
"serverReadyAction": {
    "action": "openExternally",
    "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
},
```

So the browser was keeping launching even if I removed the `"launchBrowser"` or set its `"enabled"` property to false.

Deleting the `"serverReadyAction"` section solved my issue.

Answer (score 8):

For me, commenting out the `serverReadyAction` block in `vscode/launch.json` worked. I believe the `launchBrowser` is deprecated.

More info : [Starting a Web Browser](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md#starting-a-web-browser)

[image]